# Keeping Redundant Namespace Prefixes On XML Elements in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I'm trying to write an XML file that will be picked up and parsed by another service. In order for this to happen the XML must be formatted in a very specific way, namely:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Feedbacks:Feedbacks xmlns:Feedbacks="Feedbacks">
  <Feedbacks:Elements>
    <Feedback:XMLFeedback xmlns:Feedback="Feedback">
      <Feedback:MfgUnitID></Feedback:MfgUnitID>
      <Feedback:MachineId></Feedback:MachineId>
      <Feedback:OperationCode></Feedback:OperationCode>
      <Feedback:ItemSeqNum></Feedback:ItemSeqNum>
      <Feedback:OperDispositionCd></Feedback:OperDispositionCd>
      <Feedback:ItemId></Feedback:ItemId>
      <Feedback:ParentItemId></Feedback:ParentItemId>
      <Feedback:ItemEndSize>1821</Feedback:ItemEndSize>
      <Feedback:ItemDispositionCd></Feedback:ItemDispositionCd>
      <Feedback:OperStartDate></Feedback:OperStartDate>
      <Feedback:OperEndDate></Feedback:OperEndDate>
    </Feedback:XMLFeedback>
  </Feedbacks:Elements>
</Feedbacks:Feedbacks>
```

with data of course between the innermost elements. Here's the issue though, no matter what I do, I can't get any of the C# classes to keep the semicolons on the innermost nodes. As far as I know these need to stay, so is there a way in C# to force it to format the nodes this way? I've tried all of the create methods that I could find in the XMLDocument class. I can get the outer nodes formatted fine, but the inner ones just keep creating problems.

Edit, sorry here's the code that makes the inner nodes.

```
private void AppendFile(string filename, string[] headers, Dictionary<string, string> values)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filename);
        XmlNode node = doc.GetElementsByTagName(headers[headers.Length - 2]).Item(0);
        string[] hPieces = headers[headers.Length - 1].Split(':');
        XmlElement appendee = doc.CreateElement(hPieces[0].Trim(), hPieces[1].Trim(), hPieces[0].Trim());
        node.AppendChild(appendee);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in values)
        {
            string[] ePieces = pair.Key.Split(':');
            //XmlElement element = doc.CreateElement(ePieces[0].Trim(), string.Empty, ePieces[1].Trim());
            //XmlText text = doc.CreateTextNode(pair.Value);
            XmlNode innerNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, ePieces[1].Trim(), ePieces[0].Trim());
            node.InnerText = pair.Value;
           // element.AppendChild(text);
            appendee.AppendChild(innerNode);
        }

        doc.Save(filename);
    }
```

The data for the inner nodes comes in as key value pairs in the dictionary. Where the keys contain the intended name.

Edit2: This is what the file output looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feedbacks:Feedbacks xmlns:Feedbacks="Feedbacks">
  <Feedbacks:Elements>
    <Feedback:XMLFeedback xmlns:Feedback="Feedback">
      <MfgUnitID></MfgUnitID>
      <MachineId></MachineId>
      <OperationCode</OperationCode>
      <ItemSeqNum></ItemSeqNum>
      <OperDispositionCd></OperDispositionCd>
      <ItemId></ItemId>
      <ParentItemId></ParentItemId>
      <ItemEndSize></ItemEndSize>
      <ItemDispositionCd></ItemDispositionCd>
      <OperStartDate></OperStartDate>
      <OperEndDate></OperEndDate>
    </Feedback:XMLFeedback>
  </Feedbacks:Elements>
</Feedbacks:Feedbacks>
```

Comment: Well what *does* happen? Can you show your code? I wouldn't expect the .NET parsers to throw away namespace information...

Comment: have you tried XSD.exe?  You can parse the desired xml with XSD.exe and it will generate a C# class that you can serialize...

Comment: Those are XML Namespaces, or that's what they look like, anyway.  They have a specific meaning in XML, which is why you're getting batty behaviour; XMLDocument is treating them like namespaces, not as part of the XML tag proper.

Comment: Show us your code.  We can't do anything without seeing the code you're using for this.

Comment: Done, also if XSD.exe is really the way to go could someone direct me to a good place to learn use that? The Microsoft articles were awful.

Comment: xsd.exe pathtoyourfile.xml /classes

Comment: OR - you can directly create the xsd file from within `vs` - simply: open the xml file, goto the `XML menu` and then select `Create Schema`, it'll then automatically get created and reside in the editor window. then bake at gas mark 6 till golden brown... :-)

Comment: Would it be easy to append to the file using XSD? If more data comes in I need to keep appending this piece to a larger file.

Comment: About "needing the exact format", were you _told_ that you need the exact format, or did you try the "Edit2" version of your code and it didn't work? Because any program that understands XML should treat the two identically. It would be a serious bug in the other program if it needed "Feedback:" on those inner elements.

Comment: I was told, though there may be a way for me to check to see if that other program would recognize the edit2 version. That's actually the answer I've gotten from a lot of places which is why I wanted to "force" c# to do it the original way, since I'm coming to the understanding that its not really right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accompish this easily with XLinq:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

     XNamespace ns1 = "Feedbacks";
     XNamespace ns2 = "Feedback";

     var doc = new XElement("Feedbacks", 
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns+"Feedbacks", ns1));

     doc.Add(new XElement(ns1 + "Elements", 
            new XElement(ns2 + "Feedback", 
               new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns+"Feedback", ns2),
               new XElement(ns2 + "Unit"))));
```

Gives

```
<Feedbacks xmlns:Feedbacks="Feedbacks">
  <Feedbacks:Elements>
    <Feedback:Feedback xmlns:Feedback="Feedback">
      <Feedback:Unit />
    </Feedback:Feedback>
  </Feedbacks:Elements>
</Feedbacks>
```

Although I believe that your own output should be valid XML, relying on the parent namespcae.

Comment: This may work, but I need to target .NET 2.0, and I think these classes are only 3.5 and above.